Creating Scoped Service but unable to provide a value for the property on use as no registered service
I am attempting to store the selected Group ID (room) to then be referenced by other components on the client with SignalR however I im consistently getting the below error
InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'RoomState' on type 'BlazorSignalRApp.Client.Pages.Components.JoinRoom'. There is no registered service of type 'BlazorSignalRApp.Client.RoomStateService'.
Please can someone identify where I'm going wrong with this and let me know what I can do to improve and get it to work?
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoomStateService, RoomStateService>();

IRoomStateService.cs
{
    public interface IRoomStateService
    {
        string? RoomId { get; set; }
        event EventHandler? OnRoomIdChanged;
    }
}

RoomStateService.cs
namespace BlazorSignalRApp.Client;
public class RoomStateService : IRoomStateService
{
    private string? roomId;

    public string? RoomId
    {
        get => roomId;
        set
        {
            if (roomId != value)
            {
                roomId = value;
                OnRoomIdChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler? OnRoomIdChanged;
}

JoinRoom.razor
@inject IRoomStateService RoomState

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Join room</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Enter the room ID to join a room.</p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" @bind="roomId" placeholder="Enter Room ID" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="StoreRoomId">Store Room ID</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private string? roomId;

    private void StoreRoomId()
    {
        RoomState.RoomId = roomId;
    }
}


You are registering IRoomStateService in DI - not RoomStateService.
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoomStateService, RoomStateService>();

So inject:
@inject IRoomStateService RoomState

will work.

I've used that and unfortunately it still isn't working

Net version? Interactivity type?  Interactivity location?  There are things you're  not telling us.

Are you running a .NET8 Blazor WebApp here (with a web and a web.client project)? If so you might need to register the service in DI on the server program.cs as well as the client - if its server rendered or prerendered on the server this could be your issue?
